# How to get authorization header value in .NET Core Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, header, authorization, asp.net-core-webapi

I am working with JWT tokens in my backend and my question is how I can read the value of the authorization header, when I have a [Authorize] annotation above my method. I need the token, because in its payload a user id is saved and I need the ID to perform several actions (of course the token gets verified first).

In my frontend, I am adding the authorize header as the following:

```
axios.post(finalurl, {accessToken: localStorage.accessToken}, {headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${(localStorage.accessToken)}`
        }})
```

In my backend:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<UserWithToken>> PutUser(int id, [FromForm] User user)
{
    // ....
}
```

I know that it would also be possible to transfer the token as an object in the body, but this would make the thing more complicated, because when I am using this way I always have to create new Models that inherit from the object I want to transfer and gets an additional token attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to get the user ID and it's stored as a claim in the token, you can get it through the `HttpContext` like so:

```cs
HttpContext.User?
    .Claims?
    .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub)?
    .Value
```

Of course, if you use a different claim type, you can replace `JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub` with whatever your claim is called.

`HttpContext.User` is the `ClaimsPrincipal` of the user associated with the current request.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<UserWithToken>> PutUser(int id, [FromForm] User user)
{
var token = string.Empty;
var header = (string)HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
if (header != null) token = header.Substring(7);
.....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the following method by adding a parameter `[FromHeader]` which is working

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<UserWithToken>> PutUser(int id, [FromForm] User user, [FromHeader] string authorization)
{
    // ....
}
```